# Swap common column value to same column for specific rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a data frame containing two columns of gene symbols. 
If a gene symbol in the first column is also found in the second column, I wish for the second column value to be switched into the first column.

For a basic example:

```
gene1 <- c("A2M", "A2M", "CDKN1A")
gene2 <- c("AMBP", "ANXA6", "A2M")
df <- cbind(gene1, gene2)
names(df) <- c("gene1", "gene2")
```

Produces:

```
gene1   gene2
1 A2M    AMBP
2 A2M    ANXA6
3 CDKN1A A2M
```

I want the output to switch "A2M" in the third row so that it is in the gene1 column and "CDKN1A" will be in the gene2 column.

Like this:

```
gene1   gene2
1 A2M    AMBP
2 A2M    ANXA6
3 A2M    CDKN1A
```

How would I do this for all values in the first column?

Comment: `df[df$gene2 %in% df$gene1,] <- df[df$gene2 %in% df$gene1, 2:1]`

Comment: @Ryan's solution is correct. have to convert `gene1` and `gene2` to characters with `df$gene1<-as.character(df$gene1); df$gene2<-as.character(df$gene2)` but otherwise it will work

Comment: Thank you, I did have to convert to characters first to avoid a warning message. `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 3L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`